# R’ Hurewitz’s response to prof. Louis Ginzburg about grape juice

Tags: grapes-wine, responsa

Does anybody know where I can find R’ Hurewitz’s response to prof. Louis Ginzburg about grape juice?

Thanks!

Comment: You should summarize the question precisely.

Comment: What is it about? Also, which Rabbi Hurewitz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Yitzhok Simhah Horowitz’s written response/challenge of Prof. Ginzberg’s responsum was published in his commentary Yad HaLevi on Rambam’s Sefer HaMitzvot, beginning [s.v. ונראה](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38150&st=&pgnum=271&hilite=).

Comment: You should summarize the answer.